# How to create a free GCP Compute Engine VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, free

Using the GCP Price calculartor I get:

1 x    e2-micro    730 total hours per month   USD 0.00

But when I try to create such instance I get a price estimate of

2 vCPU + 1 GB memory    USD6.11

Disco persistente balanceado de 10 GB   USD1.00

Sustained use discount  -USD0.00

Total   USD7.1

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Free/credits are applied to the project billing account and not at the time you create an instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still do not understand what I get for free.

Comment: Do you mean I can create the instance with Total USD7.1 and I will be invoiced USD0.0 nevertheless?

Comment: If the instance qualifies, yes.

Comment: I created the instance. I will confirm if I have no costs in one month, for that could help others. Thanks.

Comment: Not free. I got charges this month. Not that I do not want to pay if necessary, but still I really would like to know "what can I get for free?".

Comment: @AntonioGarcia - the details on why you are changed for any service are in the billing statement. You receive a certain quota of free services each month. Compare what you are eligible for with the billing statement.

Comment: "a certain quota of free services each month" That is what I struggle to know, but I must be  too dumb and I have been unable to find it. I give up. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to give a look to the VM instance pricing in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing)

Basically, it mentions that the following billing model applies to **all** *vCPUs*, *GPUs*, *and memory resources*. The billing model also applies to several premium images that you run on Compute Engine instances

All *vCPUs, GPUs*, and *GB of memory* are charged a minimum of `1 minute`. For example, if you run your virtual machine for 30 seconds, you will be billed for 1 minute of usage.

After 1 minute, instances are charged in `1 second` increments.

On the other hand, Said documentation also mentions: "See the estimated costs of your instances and Compute Engine resources when you create them in the Google Cloud Console" so that's the reason of the total amount of USD 7.1 you had when tried to create the instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read that document. It is at it's end that I found the Price calculator, that gave me USD0.00, but still I do not know what I get for free, or how to get it.